# Deletion of microsost-word-2011

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Typo in name. Currently with one question.

https://superuser.com/tags/microsost-word-2011/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have retagged the single question that was tagged [microsost-word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsost-word-2011) to [microsoft-word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2011).

There is a [tag cleanup script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags) that runs daily that should clean up the erroneous tag.